# Why am I getting an error when trying to import a repository from one DevOps organization from another?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, devops, azure-powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm attempting to use powershell and the DevOps Rest API to import a repository from one DevOps organization to another.  I'm receiving an error when creating the Service Endpoint and i'm not sure why.

I know I can do this manually, but I need to move approximately 300 repositories... so i'm hoping to do this via script.

Here is the error:
Could not create Endpoint: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"At least one project reference required to create an endpoint.","typeName":"System.ArgumentException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

Relevant code:

```
$DestinationEndpointURL = $DestinationURLBase/$DestinationProjectName/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=6.0-preview.4"

 # create endpoint
$ServiceConnection = Invoke-RestMethod $DestinationEndpointURL -Headers $DestinationHeader



if (($ServiceConnection).value.name -contains "Git Import") {
    Write-Output "INFO: ServiceConnection already exists"
    $DestinationEndpoint = $ServiceConnection.value
}
else {
    Write-Output "INFO: Creating ServiceConnection"
    $body = @{
        "name" = "Git Import"
        "type" = "git"
        "url" = "https://$SourceOrganizationName@dev.azure.com/$SourceOrganizationName/$SourceProjectName/_git/$SourceRepoName"
        "authorization" = @{
            "parameters" = @{
                "username" = "$UserName"
                "password" = "$SourceToken"
            }
            "scheme" = "UsernamePassword"
        }
    }
    $Parameters = @{
        Uri         = $DestinationEndpointURL
        Method      = "POST"
        ContentType = "application/json"
        Headers     = $DestinationHeader
        Body        = ( $body | ConvertTo-Json )
    }
    Try {
        $DestinationEndpoint = Invoke-RestMethod @Parameters
    }
    Catch {
        Throw "Could not create Endpoint: $_"
    }
}


# import repository
$body = @{
    "parameters" = @{
        "deleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone" = ($LoopCount -eq $AllSourceRepos.Count)
        "gitSource" = @{
            "url"       = "https://$SourceOrganizationName@dev.azure.com/$SourceOrganizationName/$SourceProjectName/_git/$SourceRepoName"
        }
        "serviceEndpointId" = $DestinationEndpoint.id
        "tfvcSource" = $null
    }
}
$Parameters = @{
    uri = "$DestinationURLBase/$DestinationProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/$DestinationRepoName/importRequests?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
    Method = 'Post'
    ContentType = "application/json"
    Headers = $DestinationHeader
    Body = ($body | ConvertTo-Json)
}



Try {
    Write-Output "INFO: Importing Repository to $DestinationProjectName $DestinationRepoName"
    Invoke-RestMethod @Parameters
}
Catch {
    Throw "Could not import Repo: $_"
}
Write-Verbose "INFO: Done with Repo $DestinationReponame"
break;
```

Any ideas here?

Comment: Are you aware of the limitations of the "import" feature? It does not handle Git LFS objects and only imports a limited subset of history (I believe 6 months). If you want to ensure that you're capturing everything, you'd be better off scripting it out using Git CLI commands.